# Host Unreachable through browser but can be ping

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, proxy, firewall

I have setup a web server, and then it's working fine when accessed through browser. Suddenly the site cannot be reached anymore (Host unreachable). I can ping the Ubuntu server but cannot accessed it through browser. It has no http errors. I can access internet.

Port 80 is open when I tried the commands below:

```
nmap 192.168.5.141
nmap localhost
```

If it has to do with proxy or firewall. Please guide me what to do since Im a newbie in managing Ubuntu servers.

Answer (score 1):

Please include more details about the web server you set up, software, version and how you set it up.
Have you check logs on the web server you set up in /var/log/yourwebserver

Can you verify the server is running 
ps aux | grep webserver

Also, verify you can reach the server by running:
netcat -z -v 192.168.5.141 80

Running 
netstat -tulpn | grep 80

Will usually give you a better view as well for future

You have not posted what firewall you are using, so it's impossible to troubleshoot this part. It sounds like the service failed if you could access it before.